# android tapjacking prevention in manifest sufficient?

Tags: android, security, clickjacking

Been reading up on Android [tapjacking](https://blog.lookout.com/blog/2010/12/09/android-touch-event-hijacking/) and its prevention but was wondering if its just sufficient to set this attribute in the application theme? OR do we also need to set this on all buttons we have in our apps (created via XML and code)?

Comment: Six year old article, I believe this is fixed now

Comment: its still happenign if you stack two fragments ontop of each other both with edit texts. api 27 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50944049/android-two-fragments-stacked-ontop-of-each-other-using-transactional-add-ho